# convert super model into inner model

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I have backbone models hierarchy like

```
ModelA = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize : function(){
         this.set("prop1",10);
    }
});

ModelB = ModelA.extend({
    this.set("prop2",new ModelC())
});
ModelD = ModelA.extend({
    this.set("prop3",new ModelE())
});
```

ModelC and ModelE are also Backbone models.

I wanted to store ModelB and ModelD objects into 1 collection  So

I created collection like

```
collection = Backbone.Collection({
   model : ModelA
});
```

Here what I'm doing -

1. I store ModelA objects into collection
2. Converting collection into json.
3. Recreating collection from json.

Here I'm getting ModelA objects from collection but want objects of specific type like ModelB, ModelD  etc.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why not just add an extra attribute to the models, specifying the type ("ModelA", "ModelB", etc)?

Comment: @McGarnagle You would loose any extra functions defined in the child models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trick it into creating the correct Model as @McGarnagle said by providing an attribute that specifies the type then specify a custom constructor for your collection,

```
collection = Backbone.Collection({
   model : function(attrs, options){
        if(!attrs || !attrs.modelType)
          return new ModelA(attrs, options)

        if(attrs.modelType === 'ModelB')
          return new ModelB(attrs, options)

        //etc...
   }
});
```